# Data distribute in large cluster with many indices (Elasticsearch)

Tags: search, elasticsearch

I have  a cluster with 30 nodes and a lot  of indices with small number of primary shards . Let's say 800 indices . most indices only have 1 or 2 primary shards.
I want to know how elasticsearch cluster distribute data across the cluster such a lot of small indices?
Does all nodes in cluster receive data evenly ? or near evenly ?
Thanks,
Sun Chanras

Answer (score 1):

> The cluster reorganizes itself to spread the data evenly.

You can read it [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_an_empty_cluster.html)

For your specific case you cane use [kopf](https://github.com/lmenezes/elasticsearch-kopf), A greate plugin that visualize the location of all  shards in each node.
I think that there are more similar plugins but this is the only one that i worked with.